# App needs access to customer google cloud project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I want to build some service where one customer / company can provide a google cloud storage bucket + firestore db and i want to perform some operations on the bucket files and firestore (read/write) but i'm not sure whats the best way to get access to their resources.

```
[my gc project] -> [customer 1 gc project: bucket + firestore]
                -> [customer 2 gc project: bucket + firestore]
                -> [customer n gc project: bucket + firestore]
```

Solutions i can imagine:

- Request access with OAuth but then its more like the user gives me the permissions and not the company
- The customer creates a service account and gives me the "json"
- I create a service account for each customer and he has to add it to his project, i don't know if thats possible and i think there is a limit of about 100 service accounts per customer
- I create one service account and each customer has to add it to his projects

Some other requirements:

- I need access to the customer project in a way that i can run scheduled jobs in background
- I have to access the customer project with google cloud functions

What would be the best fit for me or am i missing something?

Comment: I think you can explore on [Cloud Identity and Access Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam) which I think it can help you with what you're after. Note that each product has its own Cloud IAMs, you may want to read more about it on [GCS Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam) and [Firestore Cloud IAM](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/iam). Let me know if this fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If the projects will be created by you on their behalf, I would suggest to create an organization. In an organization projects are classified in folders, similar to a file system. Then, you can add the access control to specific elements to all the projects inside. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/resource-hierarchy-access-control

Otherwise, you will have to manually (or create a script) to ask for a service account (second dot) or create on unique service account and add this unique service account to each customer project (third dot).

Comment: To comply with some policies i would like to they are the owner of the projects. So when i create them i have to make them the owner and then remove most of my privileges. In case of options 2. and 3. what would you recommend to go for?

Comment: I would personally focus on creating a script that gives permissions to one service account. That script can be run from the Cloud Shell to make it easy to your customers